# ListView inside Repeater Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, repeater

I have a class like

```
class BroadCast
{
    public string Comment{ get; set; }
    public DateTime Date{ get; set; }
    public List<string> DisplayUsers { get; set; }
}
```

I am binding `List<BraodCast>` to `Repeater`. Till now I had only two columns in `Repeater` but I need to add one more now to display list of `DisplayUsers`. I am thinking to use `ListView` inside repeater so I bound it like below

```
<asp:ListView ID="lstDisplayRole" runat="server" DataSource='<%# Eval("DisplayUsers") %>'  >
   <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:Label ID="lblRoleName" runat="server" ForeColor="Black" Text='<%#Eval(index)%>' />
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

`index` is nothing, I am finding what could be there to make my listview work. I mean if it was a `DataTable` instead of `List<string>` than it would have been very easy to use `Eval("ColumnName")` but this is not a case here, I don't have columns, it's just a list of string. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the current bound item itself (a `string` in this case), use `Container.DataItem`. There's nothing to *evaluate*, so `Eval()` isn't needed.

```
<asp:Label ID="lblRoleName" runat="server" ForeColor="Black" Text='<%# Container.DataItem %>' />
```

Comment: Wow. Worked so well. Can I format this as a <li> tag?

Comment: Yeah, you can skip the `Label`. `<li><%# Container.DataItem %></li>` should be permitted right within the `<ItemTemplate>`. If not, use a nested repeater instead, so you can use the header/footer templates to open and close the `<ul>`.